# JavaScript: Callback which doesn't stop execution of lines below

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, callback, requirejs

Before this question, I already thought that I had mastered JavaScript.. but no, not even close :)

I'm currently programming with require.js and trying to make methods with callbacks (because of async js) but the problem is that code continues execution after my **callback();** calls.

See following example:

```
var Second = function () {
    console.log("Second init");
};

Second.prototype.load = function (callback) {

    console.log("Second load");

    var timeOut = setTimeout(function () {

        clearTimeout(this);

        if (true) {
            console.log("Second interval ended.. GOOD");
            callback(true);
        }

        console.log("Second interval ended.. NO, YOU SHOULD NOT BE HERE!");
        callback(false);

    }, 1000);
};

var First = function () {

    console.log("First init");
    var second = new Second();

    second.load(function (returned) {
        console.log("Second returned: " + returned);
    });

};

First();
```

This will output:

```
First init
Second init
Second load
Second interval ended.. GOO
Second returned: true
Second interval ended.. NO, YOU SHOULD NOT BE HERE!
Second returned: false
```

Where obviously two last lines are too much... What I would want't is a proper way to do callback in following scenarion.. I tried:

```
if (true) {
    console.log("Second interval ended.. GOOD");
    return callback(true);
}
```

Which works, and:

```
if (true) {
    console.log("Second interval ended.. GOOD");
    return function() {
       callback(true);
    }
}
```

Which works too, but both of them feels like wrong solutions to me.. how to do this correctly?, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be a matter of opinion, but `return callback()` is typically the standard. You can see it used this way in the Node source. Example from the filesystem module:

```
fs.fstat(fd, function(er, st) {
  if (er) return callback(er);
  size = st.size;
  if (size === 0) {
    // the kernel lies about many files.
    // Go ahead and try to read some bytes.
    buffers = [];
    return read();
  }

  buffer = new Buffer(size);
  read();
});
```

Comment: Ok, great :) - it just feels a bit absurd, I thought that it was my own silly invention to try "return callback();" - I will accept this shortly if there are no more opinions about the subject, thnx!

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any official documentation (although you can count the official Node source as a decent indicator of how things should be used). However, `return` is either for providing a result value, or breaking out of a function. Creating a new scope for a return value has no effect, so you can assume `return callback()` is the best way to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Now that I modified my sources to use that, it doesn't look that bad, I roll with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want code executed after you have called your callback, just don't place any there. If you hadn't placed a `console.log` statement after your call to the callback function nothing would have happened: your function would simply have returned.

Comment: How do you code the problem case then.. what if I have 50 lines below  to do something else if value is false? I could do if and else blocks and let code continue after callback, but I consider it as ugly code.

Comment: What is wrong with `if (something) {callback();} else { /* do something else */ }`. There's nothing magical about a callback - it's just a function. I'm sorry - I just don't see a problem here.

Comment: The question wasn't related to "if else" programming style, it was about behavior of proper callbacks. I have used if(condition) { return something; } /* do something else without blocks */ return something; way too long to stop now because of broken callback ;)